# Why use NSArray instead of NSOrderedSet

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

In many good articles online, including this one: http://nshipster.com/nsorderedset/ it is stated that we should still prefer `NSArray` over `NSOrderedSet` in general.

An advantage that i've noticed is the syntactic sugar of `NSArray`: `@[obj1, obj2, ...]`

So what are the other advantages of `NSArray` that makes it the preferred collection manager instead of `NSOrderedSet`, which seems to have a lot of benefits (fast access to elements), and it basically includes the `NSArray` functionality?

Comment: A *set* and an *array* are different things, so how can they be compared?  Doesn't it depend on what you want to use them for?

Comment: Array can store duplicates but set let you store only distinct objects.

Comment: Ignore the part with duplicates. That is usually handled in code.

Comment: FYI `NSArray` has existed since ios2.0 and `NSOrderedSet` came out in ios 5.0 which likely accounts for NSArray being around more.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I timed inserting 1,000,000 random `NSNumbers` and found that `NSMutableOrderedSet` was about 7 to 10 times slower. With fewer items the times became closer, at 1000 items the times were about 2.5 times slower.  Access times were close.

These times represent about the best for NSMutableOrderedSet that I saw:

iterations: 1000000

NSMutableOrderedSet: 782 msec
count: 999868

NSMutableArray: 112 msec
count: 1000000

Note that there were 132 duplicates that were rejecter by `NSMutableOrderedSet`.

Comment: Yes, insertion is slower, and if you don't really use `objectAtIndex` a lot and you usually iterate through the collection i guess it makes no sense to use `NSOrderedSet` as an `NSArray`, instead of just using `NSArray` from the start

Comment: i meant in the comment above the `containsObject:` method

Comment: Access time were close? If you were comparing `NSArray objectAtIndex:` of course it will be close, but the whole advantage of a set is to know quickly if an object is already inside or not. In that regard you should compare with `NSArray indexOfObject:`.

Answer (score 0):

The best advice is: Use NSOrderedSet only if you NEED its specific features.

1. To impose uniqueness (same object cannot be inserted more than
   once). Any implementation of that using NSArray - will be same, or
   slower than NSArray.
2. To quickly check if an object already exists in your collection - here NSOrderedSet will be MUCH faster - O(1) than NSArray - O(N)

Otherwise - (if you don't need the Set features) use NSArray of course.